# multiple regexes on single string

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

I have been looking for  solution to figure out how to apply multiple regexes using `|` (or) condition but it does not seem to work. Can someone shine some light on it? Here is what I have been trying to do. I searched StackOverflow for a solution and posting it here.
This is javascript language.

```
regex1 = "/d", regex2 = "/W"
```

merging both using `|` like this `regex3 = new Regex(regex1+"|"+regex2,"gi");`
This seems to work fine.

When I try to use the same login for lookahead, it fails.

Text to be searched:  `Red _Red 'Red test`
eg:

```
regex1 = "(?:^)red" , regex2 = "(?=[_])red"
regex3 = new Regex(regex1+"|"+regex2, "gi");
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Should your `red` in `(?:^)red` and `(?=[_])red` be uppercase `Red`?

Comment: @S.Kablar the `i` flag is used.

Comment: the search term can be "red" and it should match 30 different scenarios like
'red',-red,~red  and many other special characters and it has to be at the beginning of it.
There is one scenario where if the text is "red_red_red", it should consider each red as individual term and match the all  if "red" starts at the beginning. so it should match 
'redTag but not tagred as the term red is not at the beginning in the second word.

Comment: Try `(?<=_)Red|^Red` https://regex101.com/r/AAgPp8/1

Comment: @S.Kablar lookbehinds only work in Chrome 62+ at the moment

Comment: Also, I am not asking for solution to my problem but trying to understand why parallel regexes do not work in second case. So whatever I gave was just an example. I will take help if I cannot come up with anything for my actual issue. Thanks for quick replies, all.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with look-arounds is that they are "zero-width assertions" that don't actually match anything, so `(?=_)red` can never match "_red", because the "_", while *seen* by the lookahead, is never actually able to match.

We *could* fix your pattern like this:

```
(?:^)red|((?=[_]).)red
```

https://regex101.com/r/H9VSzQ/2/

Or simply get rid of the redundant lookahead (and the single-character character class!) and go ahead and match that underscore:

```
(?:_|^)red
```

https://regex101.com/r/flUTmp/1

Comment: Thank you sweaver2112. I added a character class because I had to apply other scenarios ~,?<>#$%&^*(      just like "_". So I was planning to apply regex as follows
(?:^)red|((?=[~,?<>#$%&^*(_]).)red

Comment: Thank you all for responding so quickly. I did not find the solution for it but had to change the paradigm to resolve the issue.